# Is it possible to download the OpenRailwayMap tiles?

Tags: openstreetmap

I'd like to do an experimental visualization with OpenRailwayMap tiles, however they take long to load from the official server using leaflet. I was thinking about downloading all the tiles I need, but since the server is slow, I would think of it as "bad attitude" to bomb it with requests until I have all the tiles; and if I wait after each tile, it would take forever.

Is there any way to download all the tiles I need en block from somewhere?

As an alternative, I could render them for myself, but all the documentation I found on rendering OSM data describes how to set up live-rendering servers (which I do not need), and, more important, I do not know the OpenRailwayMap render settings.

Comment: Do you use QGIS? You can download the tiles using that. It depends on the volume of data you need. What is the area of interest?

Comment: No, I am using `wget https://a.tiles.... -w <waittime>` at the moment. We are talking about a relatively small area (<0.5° x 0.5°), but that gives many tiles in high zoom levels as well. Or is such a small area neglectible?